# Как обновить библиотеку?

Tags: python, update, библиотеки

Как обновить библиотеку? Хочу обновить одну из питоновских библиотек. Как это сделать? Те у меня есть `python-lib_a_1.3`, а я хочу `python-lib_a_1.9`.

Answer (score 2):

Или так

```
pip install -U libname
```

или даже так

```
easy_install -U libname
```

Answer (score 1):

Всё зависит от дистрибутива, смотрите в каком пакете лежит эта библиотека и обновляйте через систему работы с пакетами (или ебилдами).easy_install крайне плохой выход потом замучаетесь вычищать если что не так... так как easy_uninstall нету.

Answer (score 0):

```
 sudo apt-get install python-lib-a-1.9
```

может быть так..

Answer (score 0):

Всё выше написанное правильно,но лучше использовать синаптик- в поисковике написать piton.И появится список всего, что с ним связано, останется только поставить галочки на выбраных пакетах, причем все зависимости будут установлены автоматом или предложены пакеты для установки зависимостей